# How can I recover from a frozen fullscreen application / game?

Tags: ssh, performance

A few times now, Starcraft 2 has frozen up on my wife's Macbook Pro, but the mouse pointer still moves and the sound keeps playing.  I can also SSH in from a different machine.  The keyboard shortcut for force-quit doesn't work though, and nothing in-game is clickable.  Command-tab won't switch windows either.

If this were a straight-up Linux box, I'd find the application process and kill it from an SSH login.  If that failed, I might take out the X server.  Can I do anything like this in OSX?  Is there something on the "problem" machine I can do locally instead?

Comment: All process management you'd do on Linux exists equally as much in OS X.

Answer (score 5):

1. Search for the Starcraft 2 process in the process list. I don't know the name of the binary but something like `ps aux | grep -i starcraft` should get you there
2. The number in the second column is the PID
3. `kill PID` or (if this doesn't work) `kill -9 PID` (if you are not the owner of the process, you can use `sudo kill ...` instead)

Depending on the process structure of Starcraft 2 you may need to do this several times to hit the right one.

Comment: If you know the name of the process (e.g. this one is probably "Starcraft 2"), a shorter path is `killall 'Starcraft 2'`. (Caution: Do not generalize this advice to other UNIX systems; `killall` may mean kill *everything*.)

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the process list that looked like "starcraft", "blizzard", or "sc2" -- that's why I figured the next step up the chain was "log the user out".  I realize it's sort of the "low-yield nuclear option" but IMHO it's better than a hard power cycle.

Comment: In this case, you should find the Starcraft process. Maybe you don't have the full list of processes. I use `ps -ax`. Try this.